# Web sites with famous game information?

Tags: mathematics, graphics, camera, rpg

Is there any website containing informations related with some famous game? For *information* I mean how to calculate damage in a rpg for example, or how they've set camera and other tips like this! 
Games I'm interested in are games like the legend of zelda, league of legends,tales of series, final fantasy, super mario, online mmorpg, halo, metroid, WoW, etc. and some indie games such as games on steam (spiral knights, bastion etc)

I think it could be usefull to have a reference based on games of a certain importance both for our games and for game development culture, in general. Thanks in advance

Comment: Whoa... I feel that's a wealth of information you're asking for! I think you should narrow down a bit what you mean by 'famous game'. Or at least stick with a genre.

Comment: Yeah!I'm going to edit the question

Comment: Sounds like you've got a business idea. I'm sure this site would generate plenty of ad revenue.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for FAQs on a Game. There might be a [website for that](www.gamefaqs.com). [Or two.](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I didn't know that gamefaqs has this kind of stuff! For example I found Final Fantasy XIII battle mechanics. Very helpful